# Parse deeply nested tree, return all parents

Tags: python, xml

I have this XML:

```
<nodes>
  <node id="1">
    <nodes>
      <node id="7">
        <nodes>
          <node id="9">
            <nodes>
              <node id="5">
                <nodes>
                  <node id="4">
                    <nodes>
                      <node id="3">
                        <nodes />
                        <variables>
                          <variable id="5"  />
                          <variable id="1"  />
                          <variable id="8"  />
                          <variable id="1"  />
                          <variable id="9"  />
                        </variables>
                      </node>
                    </nodes>
                    <variables>
                      <variable id="4"  />
                      <variable id="6"  />
                      <variable id="8"  />
                    </variables>
                  </node>
                </nodes>
              </node>
            </nodes>
          </node>
        </nodes>
      </node>
    </nodes>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

I would like to get the nodes which have variables assigned to them: 
That said I would like have this output:

`[node_id: [variable_ids]]
['3': ['5','1','8','9'], '4': ['4','6','8']]`

I started with the following XML parsing:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

def iterate_node(eq):
    text = ""
    for node in eq:
        if 'id' in node.keys():
            text = text + " { ID: " +  node.attrib['id'] + " TAG: " + node.tag + " }"
        text = text + iterate_node(node)
    return text

for node_root in root.findall('nodes'):
    print(node_root.tag)
    for eq in node_root:
        print(iterate_node(eq))
```

But this code doesn't add up all the variables per node. How would you parse this XML? **Thank you**

Comment: Could my approach work for you and solve the problem @John Smith?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add up all variables per node, you could use temporary lists to append your variable ids and afterwards assign them to a dictionary, where your node ids are the keys.

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlstring = '''<nodes>
...
</nodes>'''

def iterate_node(xmlstr):
    node_dict = {}
    root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
    # iterate through all elements
    for i in root.iter():
        if i.tag == 'node':
            #get key (=node id) for the dictionary
            key = i.attrib['id']
            for child in i:
                #iterate through variables
                if 'variables' == child.tag:
                    varslist_temp = []
                    for vars in child:
                        #add element (=var id) to list
                        varslist_temp.append(vars.attrib['id'])
                    #assign the set to the dict to clear double values
                    node_dict[key] = (set(varslist_temp))

                # the following else-statement adds "empty" nodes to your dict
                # eg.{'1': 'None', '7': 'None', ...
                #else:
                    #node_dict[key] = 'None'
    return node_dict

print(iterate_node(xmlstring))
node_dict = iterate_node(xmlstring)
# {'4': {'8', '6', '4'}, '3': {'8', '9', '5', '1'}}
```

In your approach it looks like you'd like to receive one output per node. You could use the following statement to get the dictionary items one after another.

```
for item in node_dict.items():
    print(item)
#('4', {'8', '4', '6'})
#('3', {'8', '9', '5', '1'})
```

If the (only used) else-statement is "activated" this example would produce the following output:

```
('1', 'None')
('7', 'None')
('9', 'None')
('5', 'None')
('4', {'6', '8', '4'})
('3', {'1', '9', '8', '5'})
```

Comment: Thanks, and great that you pinged me

Comment: Sorry for rating it late